# Configurable variations showing all attributes ignores attribute set

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, attribute-set, magento2.4.6

Still pretty new to Magento however we're running into this issue regarding a large number of attributes from different product areas all showing.

As I see it I enter to create a product, I select the attribute set (which reloads the attributes assigned to that category). I fill everything in (except the attributes which are variable), I then click "Create Configurations".... where I am shown EVERY SINGLE attribute on the entire site whether or not they exist in the actual attribute set or not.

So lets say I'm adding a ladies dress to specify size, pattern, etc.... from attribute set "womens_dresses"

On selecting configurable variations I am shown wheel sizes for cars, length for kitchen surfaces and hundreds of other attributes which I wouldn't 'expect' to see.

Has anyone else solved this? Extension exist?

Appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: can you share with screenshot.?